# Is it possible to schedule a SILENT local notification in iOS?

Tags: ios, notifications, uilocalnotification

I am trying to schedule a notification locally as I don't have the necessary structure in the backend yet. The idea is that after a X period of time, certain conditions are validated; and if fulfilled, a regular local notification is triggered.

This could be easily achieved using a timer for instance, but some of this periods are long enough (1 hour, 24 hours) that this doesn't work.

This is how I end up thinking in the local notifications. I could schedule one with a firedate of +24hs. The thing is that I need this to be silent in order to validate the conditions.

From the `configuring a local notification` section [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html) it seems that only remote notifications can be silent, but it doesn't really say it can't be done.

Also, I've found that it is possible to trigger a local notification with nothing but the badgeNumber, and it WILL change the badge. Though the callbacks in my AppDelegate are never called.

I've seen some people say it can't be done, but haven't found a real hard official evidence stating it. Anybody managed to do this? Or know for sure this is in fact impossible? Any advice will be of great help, thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You can't have a "silent" local notification. Background fetch mode may be of use

Comment: @Paulw11 Yep, but it only works for remote notifications, right? Is there no way to wake up the app without a remote notification?

Comment: Background fetch mode is nothing to do with notifications. It is a background mode you can opt into where iOS periodically wakes your app.  Read the background modes section in the iOS application programming guide

Comment: @Paulw11 I've looked into background mode with more detail. But it seems it is impossible to define a specific moment for it to run. I need to schedule the execution at a specific moment (either N hours into the future or at Y o'clock). Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be possible. Thanks though

Comment: That's correct. You cannot schedule execution for a specific time. You can use the background fetch time to schedule local notifications for specific times. If you want to trigger background execution at a specific time then your only option is a server that sends a silent push

Comment: Right... So to sum up, I can do silent execution with background execution, but I can't schedule it to a specific time. I can schedule local notifications to a specific time, but they can't be silent. Therefore, I will have to set up remote push notifications as they can be scheduled AND silent. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I tried and had the same experience as you - the callbacks are never called when my app is not in the foreground. This is by design. The Apple documentation states that the callback is only called when your app is in the foreground `userNotificationCenter:willPresentNotification:withCompletionHandler:`https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate/1649518-usernotificationcenter?language=objc

The only callback method for receiving notifications when the app is not in the foreground is `didReceiveRemoteNotification` but unfortunately it is only for push notifications (silent or otherwise). https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate/1649518-usernotificationcenter?language=objc

Comment: So you mean that the callbacks are called when your app is in the foreground?

Comment: It's been 2 years since I worked on that app but, at the time, yes it worked when the app was in the foreground. Newer versions of iOS could have broken that.